# Check Equality of two Strings in java

Tags: java, string, equals

I've got 2 Strings and both are the same:

```
alter follower  = 2014-02-23T18:41:35Z
neuster follower= 2014-02-23T18:41:35Z
```

I do an if/else so if they're the same the program should just display values and if not it should announce the new name (follower), but somehow, **it's only doing the else statement when they're the same...**

my code;

```
///////////////////
/// New Follower Trigger
/////////////////// 

if(followdateold.toLowerCase().equals(latestfollowerdate.toLowerCase())) {
    System.out.println("Noch kein neuer Follower... :( ");
    System.out.println("Noch kein neuer Follower... :( ");
}else{
    System.out.println("alter follower= "+followdateold);
    System.out.println("neuster follower= "+latestfollowerdate);
        sendMessage("#"+YBot.MyBot.ownerchannel+"", "Danke für deinen follow, "+fname);
        FollowerChecker.Writer();

        try {
            FollowerChecker.readFile("donottouch.txt");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are you assigning values to followdateold & latestfollowerdate

Comment: Possibility of trailing or leading whitespaces?

Comment: output `followdateold.toLowerCase()` and `latestfollowerdate.toLowerCase()`

Comment: i did edit the post above with the outputs of both

Comment: The answer from kakarot helped me. i had some space somwhere i guess then. :D

Comment: considerCamelCasingYourCode itsMuchEasierToRead thanwhatyouhaveabove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its possible that there are some leading or trailing whitespaces in the 2 strings, you should trim the whitespace before comparing the strings, try this :

```
if(followdateold.trim().toLowerCase().equals(latestfollowerdate.trim().toLowerCase())) {
```

Comment: You can simplify that even further by using String.equalsIgnorecase() as documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
followdateold.equalsIgnoreCase(latestfollowerdate)
```

maybe that would work.